# CodeIgniter drop down list not populating in the correct location

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI and PHP. I have a dropdown list of countries that is populated by a table in my database. I have managed to get CI to grab and render the data via mysql, but it's populating in plain text above my form, and not instead, in the values of the drop down list. Below is the simplified code. How can I get the values in the drop down list?

My view...

```
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Country</h5>
<select name="countryselect">
<?php echo form_dropdown(countryselect);?>
</select>

<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

<?php echo form_close() ?>

</body>
```

My controller...

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pledge', 'Pledge', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|decimal|xss_clean');

        $this->load->model('country');
        $data['country'] = $this->country->get_country();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->database();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (firstname, lastname, email, pledge) VALUES (
            ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('firstname')).",
            ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('lastname')).",
            ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('email')).",
            ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('pledge')).")";

            $this->db->query($sql);

            echo $this->db->affected_rows(); 

            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My model...

```
<?php

class Country extends CI_Model
{

function get_country() {
    $this->load->database();
    $return[''] = 'please select';
    $this->db->order_by('name'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('countries'); 
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        echo '<option value="'.$return[$row['id']] = $row['name'].'">',$return[$row['id']] = $row['name'],'</option>'. "\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is a little messed up, by the way you named `country` and not `countryselect` in

```
$data['country'] = $this->country->get_country();
```

So use `$country` as variable in the view.
The most important thing is that the `form_dropdown` required an `array` as parameter, not the `option`.

Have a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html);

If you want to create the select in that way you don't need the `form_dropdown` but just regular `html`:

```
<select name="select_country"><?php echo $country; ?></select>
```

and you need to pass it to your view:

```
$this->load->view('myform', $data);
```

EDIT:

Remember that `Controller != Model != View` and you have to use them for a single purpose.

You used your controller for saving data in the DB, this is concettually wrong, you should pass the data to your model and let it perform queries...and you really should use [ActiveRecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) instead of that to prevent `sqlinjection`.

In your module you managed data, for creating the select, even if you can, the better thing is pass the query result to the controller and let it manage that.

Comment: OK so if I interpret your first point I should replace 

 `<h5>Country</h5>
<select name="countryselect">
<?php echo form_dropdown(countryselect);?>
</select>`

 with `echo form_dropdown('name', $country, 'Australia');` but I still have the issue.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my model

Comment: No, if you return from your model the string with the option you cannot use the form_dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a bit more than just to solve dropdown issue.

### 1 Codeigniter DOCUMENTATION

go to this linke :
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

then scroll down to drop_down function();

and you will understand WITH example what does this function do and how to use.

then go to

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

And you will understand how to insert data to your database.

As for most basics like not to echo out in controller nor model, you will learn it by time.

#### -------old comment

As for you Dropdown :

```
//CI Accept parameters 
echo $this->form_dropdown('NAME OF INPUT',array('optionValue'=>'label of option',...);
```

This will produce a

```
<select namr='name of input'>
    <option value='optionValue'>label of option </option>
</select>
```

### Now more importantly you model problems :

CI query builder can do data sensitization for u, and u dont need to run raw queries for simple get data call.

Example replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO donations (firstname, lastname, email, pledge) VALUES (
        ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('firstname')).",
        ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('lastname')).",
        ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('email')).",
        ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('pledge')).")";

        $this->db->query($sql);
```

With better

```
$data= array ('firstname'=>$this->input->post('firstname'),
          'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname')
//              ... etc
          );
$ins = $this->db->insert('donations',$data);
echo $this->db->affected_rows(); //or what ever
```

### 2 : class Country extends CI_Model

Should NEVER echo out !!; return $query to controller and let controller do something like

```
foreach($query->result() as $r) {
    $dropdown[] = array( $r->id => $r->name);
}
```

then return $dropdown to view where you can simply `echo form('countrySELECT',$dropdown);`

---

try to understand more about oop and implement it . never echo in controller or model;

and for your info,

```
echo "1";
$this->load->view('aViewThatEcho2');
echo "3";
```

will result in `132` not `123` because views are all pushed to output when CI is closing after finishing everything, not once you load them !.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy reply. Part 1 above... do I add this between the select element tags in the form view? Also what, in my case is input, option and label. Sorry I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: no it generate the select tag for you.. man you need to Read the documentation of CI.

Comment: I have been trying, although working with 3 files to generate one http document is overwhelming for me. Reading the doc is not going to mean I immediately understand as it's all out of context for me. But I have been trying. Also You didn't really clarify my question about where that line goes. Also what is "..." in this case?

Comment: hmm, my #1, was to fix you insert sql its not related to you original question, and ... rest of insert statement !

Comment: @square_eyes go to [this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) and scroll down to Form_dropdown;

Comment: Your first point was about the dropdown "As for you Dropdown..." I am reading that doc thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49435/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-zalaboza)